# mysql query count with out using group by, distinct or using php count

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, count

display the number or count of rows with out using group by like below.. count(name) and display the result in count if how many name..

x-Count all elements in an array, or something in an object
x-Count all elements in an array, or something in an object

```
id  |  name  |  count 
1   |  iya   |   2
2   |  iya   |   2
3   |  anna  |   1
4   |  jess  |   2
5   |  jess  |   2
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Use `COUNT() OVER` or correlated subquery.

Comment: @Akina can you show me the right syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id, name, COUNT(name) OVER (PARTITION BY name) `count`
FROM sourcetable
```

or

```
SELECT t.id, t.name, ( SELECT COUNT(s.name) 
                       FROM sourcetable s
                       WHERE s.name = t.name ) `count`
FROM sourcetable t
```